# jQuery For Loop Image Check and Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

Good afternoon Stack Overflow,

I'm inexperienced when it comes to coding in general and I've been having a problem that's doing my head in!

If you'll allow me to set the scene...

The section of the project I am currently working on involves a user picking items from a warehouse in order to fulfil a shipment and in some cases they have to pick the same item from various locations, when that needs to be done, the small "!" type icon appears next to the item.

[image]

The user then can click on the icon and choose which locations they will be retrieving the stock from, they then press confirm on the modal and when it closes it sets the text back to blue and hides the icon.

[image]

The part I am having trouble with is that once all the locations have been established, the order needs to be processed and this requires a button to be clicked on, which I only want to appear once all the "!" icons are hidden.

I know there are alot of questions based on for loops and images checks and believe me when I say I've tried hard to figure this out myself and I've tried different approaches:

```
ShowProcess = false
for (i = 0; i<Picker; i++) {
if ($('#MultiLocIcon'+i).is(':visible')){
ShowProcess = true
}

if (ShowProcess == true) {
$('#ProcessConfirm').show()
};
};
```

This obviously wouldn't work because its setting the first variable in the list to "true" and will always read it as true, therefore always showing the image, even if the "!" icon still exists in other rows.

I also tried using .each() to test each rows text color of a specific  but also had no luck:

```
var table = $('#RequestedItemsTable');
table.find('tbody > tr').each(function(){
if $('#Desc').css('color') == '#0000FF'){
//do something
```

I feel like my experience is letting me down as I still have a lot to learn and have a suspicious feeling that the solution is going to be really easy, but then again, its only easy if you know how.

If anyone could take the time to help me with this problem or offer me any advice, I'd be really grateful.

Here is a section of my code which might be useful:

Modal "Confirm" button:

```
//CONFIRM Button which will submit final picks.
'Confirm': function() {

//Reset the length loop
length = undefined;

//Remove "Multiple Location" icon from the row.
$('#icon'+id).hide();

//Change text colour back to blue to have visual confirmation that item   is ready for picking
$('#Desc'+id).css('color', '#0000FF');
$('#QtyReq'+id).css('color', '#0000FF');
$('#QtyinStock'+id).css('color', '#0000FF');

$(this).dialog('close');
```

The "!" Icon:

```
<td id= "MultiLocIcon<?=$i;?>"><?if($row->Count_Location > 1)
    {?><img src="<?=base_url();?>public/css/images/error.png" alt="LocPick" title="Multiple Locations" style="cursor: pointer;" id= "icon<?=$i;?>" onClick="$.LocPick(<?=$i;?>);"/><?}?></td>
```

Basically just need to know how my image can show once the loop checks and knows that the "!" icon is hidden from every possible row.

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: post the html dom structure

Comment: If your first example's only problem is that it "obviously wouldn't work because its setting the first variable in the list to "true" and will always read it as true", why don't you change this single line: `ShowProcess = true` to `ShowProcess &= true`? (Also, I think you would have to negate the `.is(":visible")` part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a second check in your modal logic, perhaps after your `.hide()`:

```
//Remove "Multiple Location" icon from the row.
$('#icon'+id).hide();
$('img[id^=icon]:visible').length || $('#ProcessConfirm').show();
```

What this does is combines the `:visible` pseudo-selector and a regex selector for all `img` tags with `id` starting with "icon". This assumes you won't have any other unrelated image tags with an id like "icon*". If the length is 0, it will go ahead and show the #ProcessConfirm element.

Comment: This is amazing @swornabsent, are some sort of wizard? This seems to work perfectly for me at the moment, so it's what I will roll with...thank you very much! I knew I needed to do some sort of second check, but had no idea how to go about it. Saviour.

Comment: This is good but readability suffers! (If youre the only developer dont worry about this too much)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is based off your HTML, select all the alert icons, and do a [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) psuedo selector on it. This will return all the visible alert icons, if there are none in the array, you know none of them are visible. You will need to identify them with a class, such as .alert:

```
if( $(".alert:visible").length === 0 ){
    // Do your code in here for no visible alert icons!
}
```

Comment: cool, you posted the same solution as mine. it would be good solution if you add the code along with the description :)

Comment: thank you for your input @DietrichGeorge , I'll use your advice in the future.

Answer (score 1):

simplest solution I would give is to  add a class `warning` to all the table column  which has `warning icon` & then check for visibility of the same.

```
if($('.warning:visible').length === 0){
   //all warning icons are hidden
}
```

Comment: I really liked this answer and was about to implement it into my code when I then saw the accepted answer and tried that. Thank you for your input @dreamweiver , gonna remember your advice for the future.

Answer (score 1):

When user clicks confirm on modal you should run a check on how many icons are still visible, and if the amount is 0 then show the button, like this:

```
// This searchs for every <td> with an id that contains '#MultiLocIcon'
// Then checks if the amount of those which are visible is 0 and do something
if ( $('td[id*=MultiLocIcon]').not(':visible').length === 0 ) {
    $('#ProcessConfirm').show()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input @Aramil Rey , you answer is like the accepted one. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.